# The program is Blocked after reading from the pipe

Tags: c, pipe

The read function is blocking the process after reading from the pipe and I can't understand why.
The code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int nbrecar=5;


int main()

{
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    char *buffer=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
    int pid=fork();
    
    switch(pid)
    {
        case 0://fils 1 //pere 2
            
            int pid2=fork();
            
            if (pid2==0)//fils 12 // pere 3
            {
                
                
                
                    close(fd[0]);
                    while(nbrecar>1)
                    {
                    if(sprintf(buffer,"le nbre des cars restant:%i\n",nbrecar-1)==-1){printf("Erreur");};
                    nbrecar--;
    
                    write(fd[1],buffer,strlen(buffer));
                    
                    }
                    close(fd[1]);
                    exit(0);
            }
            
            else//fils 1
            {
                    close(fd[1]);
                    char c;
                    while(read(fd[0],&c,1)==1)
                    {printf("%c",c);};
                    
                    close(fd[0]);       
                    exit(8);            

                //}
            }
            break;
        default:
        
            wait(NULL);
            free(buffer);
    }
            
            
    


}
```

The Execution:

```
le nbre des cars restant:4
le nbre des cars restant:3
le nbre des cars restant:2
le nbre des cars restant:1
```

and then the process is blocked (it should be ended).

I tried to increment the number of bytes in the write function but nothing changes.
Any solutions please?

Comment: Most C compilers don't allow you to declare a variable immediately after a case label.  Which version of which compiler are you using, and which compiler options to enable that?  (If you use `gcc -std=c2x` or something similar, you may be benefitting from the forthcoming changes in the C23 standard.)

Comment: I am using gcc  .

Comment: You aren't closing enough pipes, so the EOF indication is not being received.  In particular, the parent process is not closing the pipe, so the process reading the pipe won't get EOF.  You need to close both file descriptors in the parent before waiting.  You should review the file descriptors in the child, too — closing `fd[0]` twice is not productive.  You shouldn't need to do dynamic memory allocation for an array of just 256 bytes.  Use an ordinary local variable.

Comment: Thank you very much! I added  close(fd[0]);close(fd[1]); in the parent block just before the wait and it's worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, you aren't closing the pipe in the original process, so the child process reading from the pipe never gets EOF and block waiting for the parent to write something, even though the parent is waiting for the child to die.  Both are going to be disappointed.

Somewhat to my surprise, GCC 11.2.0 does not complain about a variable declaration immediately after a case label unless you insist with `-pedantic`.

This code works:

```
/* SO 7433-2193 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int nbrecar = 5;

int main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
    int pid = fork();

    switch (pid)
    {
    case 0:
        int pid2 = fork();

        if (pid2 == 0)
        {
            close(fd[0]);
            while (nbrecar > 1)
            {
                if (sprintf(buffer, "le nbre des cars restant: %i\n", nbrecar - 1) == -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Erreur\n");
                    break;
                }
                nbrecar--;
                write(fd[1], buffer, strlen(buffer));
            }
            close(fd[1]);
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            close(fd[1]);
            char c;
            while (read(fd[0], &c, 1) == 1)
            {
                printf("%c", c);
            }
            close(fd[0]);
            exit(8);
        }
        break;
    default:
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        int corpse;
        int status;
        while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        {
            printf("PID %5d: child %5d exited with status 0x%.4X\n",
                   getpid(), corpse, status);
        }
        free(buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It produces (for example):

```
le nbre des cars restant: 4
le nbre des cars restant: 3
le nbre des cars restant: 2
le nbre des cars restant: 1
PID 91126: child 91127 exited with status 0x0800
```

If it were my code, I'd not use a global variable for `nbrecar`, and I'd use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop to generate the numbers.  I'd also not use a `switch` like that. For a mere 256-byte array, I'd not use `malloc()` et al; an ordinary local variable is quite adequate.

---

**Rule of thumb**: If you
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
original file descriptors returned by
[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
as soon as possible.
In particular, you should close them before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions.

The rule also applies if you duplicate the descriptors with either
[`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
or
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD` or `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC`.

Even when you're not using `dup2()` and friends, it is important to make sure that the pipe is properly closed in every process that has the pipe open but is not going to use it.

---

If the parent process will not communicate with any of its children via
the pipe, it must ensure that it closes both ends of the pipe early
enough (before waiting, for example) so that its children can receive
EOF indications on read (or get SIGPIPE signals or write errors on
write), rather than blocking indefinitely.
Even if the parent uses the pipe without using `dup2()`, it should
normally close at least one end of the pipe — it is extremely rare for
a program to read and write on both ends of a single pipe.

Note that the `O_CLOEXEC` option to
[`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html),
and the `FD_CLOEXEC` and `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC` options to `fcntl()` can also factor
into this discussion.

If you use
[`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html)
and its extensive family of support functions (21 functions in total),
you will need to review how to close file descriptors in the spawned process
([`posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose.html),
etc.).

Note that using `dup2(a, b)` is safer than using `close(b); dup(a);`
for a variety of reasons.
One is that if you want to force the file descriptor to a larger than
usual number, `dup2()` is the only sensible way to do that.
Another is that if `a` is the same as `b` (e.g. both `0`), then `dup2()`
handles it correctly (it doesn't close `b` before duplicating `a`)
whereas the separate `close()` and `dup()` fails horribly.
This is an unlikely, but not impossible, circumstance.